# Softwrap in Google Earth Engine like Atom

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is it possible to activate any option in the Code Editor of Google Earth Engine similar to 'toggle softwrap' in the software Atom?

I mean, for long lines of codes that automatically continue in the next line, because lot of times are too long and the console blocks the code editor and have to move to see the full code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that option, but I recommend that you split your long lines into multiple lines to improve readability. For example:

This long line:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filter(ee.Filter.eq("WRS_PATH",133)).filter(ee.Filter.eq("WRS_ROW", 33)).filterDate("2017-03-01", "2017-10-31").sort("system:time_start")
```

is much more readable as:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("WRS_PATH",133))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("WRS_ROW", 33))
  .filterDate("2017-03-01", "2017-10-31")
  .sort("system:time_start")
```

e.g., one operation per line. This also makes it easier to disable one (or more) of the operations by simply commenting that line(s) when you are debugging.

For long strings, you can always split them into multiple lines as such:

```js
var longString = "This is part of a long string " 
+ "and this is the continuation of the long string"
```